# Execute mysql pivotable statement with php PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have Mysql prepare statement work in command line. how get I get it to work with PHP PDO prepare statement?

```
set @sql = null;
SET group_concat_max_len=15000;

select group_concat(distinct concat('sum(if(date=''',date_format(date,'%Y-%m-%d'),''',total,null)) as ', date_format(date,'dd%Y%m%d'))) into @sql from sales where date_format(date,'%m%y')='0615';

set @sql = concat('select ',@sql,'  from sales');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the group concatenation in PHP instead of SQL.

```
$pdo->query("SET group_concat_max_len = 15000");
$stmt1 = $pdo->prepare("select distinct concat('sum(if(date=''',date_format(date,'%Y-%m-%d'),''',total,null)) as ', date_format(date,'dd%Y%m%d')) as col from sales where date_format(date,'%m%y')= :mmyy";
$stmt1->execute(":mmyy" => '0615');
$cols = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$cols_string = implode(',' $cols);
$sql = "SELECT $col_string FROM sales";
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt2->execute();
```

Comment: Since I did not want to use looping, this is the closest answer. But I really want to do in a single execution statement, is it possible in any how?

Comment: The SQL code that you pasted is not a single statement, it consists of 6 separate statements.

Comment: @praHoc Since PDO doesn't allow you to execute multiple queries in a single call, you would have to make 6 queries with those statements. What's the point of that? You could write a MySQL stored procedure that does it, and then call the procedure.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not familiar with stored procedure. Can you give example base on my code?

Comment: Read the documentation at the MySQL web site. Basically, you just wrap all the code in a `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement to give it a name, then use `CALL procedureName` to run it.

Comment: Here's a tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures-in-mysql-5--net-17843

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use prepared statements with PDO in this case.

The code that you pasted is the only way to get dynamically generated statements working in pure SQL.

Since PHP is involved, you should generate that SQL in a for loop and execute it with PDO::query method.

Comment: Thank Naktibalda, I know how to do this but I thought I can use a single query string to achieve it without involve looping.